# Peer review requeset

Tags: discussion

I am looking for someone to peer review this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/70070/75001) on bitcoin.SE question [How can I setup Bitcoin to be anonymous with Tor?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor). And, to suggest edits.

*note: I was looking for a tor.SE chat actually but didn't find it, please delete this question and point me in the right direction if inappropriate.*